# AngularJS ng-repeat is not showing table data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

my controller bring data from spring app data but it does not get displayed in form. When I put constants in data it works perfectly fine.

here is my code in JS controller

```
sampleApp.controller('searchCourseController', ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http,  $routeParams, ngTableParams ) {
         $scope.courses = {};            

        $scope.searchButton=function () {
            var actionUrl = 'searchCourse';

            var textToSearch = $("#txtTitle").val();
            if (textToSearch.length == 0) {
                alert("Please provide search criteria. Blank search is not allowed");
                /* $("#loader-overlay").fadeOut();
                $("#bg-loader").fadeOut(); */
                return;
            }

            $http.get(actionUrl+"?title="+escape(textToSearch))
            .success(
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.courses = data;
                    console.log($scope.courses);
                })
            .error(
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                });
        };

        $scope.editCourseButton=function () {
            alert ("edit");
        };

    }]);
```

and my html that i am ussing to display data is following

```
<table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                      <th>Course Name</th>
                                      <th>Status</th>
                                      <th class="hidden-xs">Publishing status</th>
                                      <th class="hidden-xs">Group Name</th>
                                      <th class="hidden-xs">Rating</th>
                                   </tr>
                                </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                   <tr ng-repeat="course in $scope.courses">
                                      <td>{{course.name}}</td>
                                      <td>{{course.courseStatus}}</td>
                                      <td>{{course.coursePublishStatus}}</td>
                                      <td>{{course.courseGroupName}}</td>
                                      <td>{{course.courseRating}}</td>
                                   </tr>
                                </tbody>
                             </table>
```

What could be the problem as the same code with fixed data gets displayed in data table without an issue.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify $scope in the view, since it's not defined:

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in $scope.courses">
```

Becomes

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
```

Comment: @AmmarAli what shows up in `console.log($scope.courses)`?

Answer (score 0):

As well as omitting the $scope from $scope.courses inside the ng-repeat, you may want to use a $scope.$apply() inside your $http.get success callback to update the scope. This will update the view to the updated $scope.courses binding after a asynchronous process.

Example:

```
$http.get(actionUrl+"?title="+escape(textToSearch))
 .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.courses = data;

                $scope.$apply(); // used $scope.$apply() to update the scope.
                console.log($scope.courses);
            })
        .error(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
  });
```

Comment: if i do $scope.apply(); JS gives me following error in console Error: $digest already in progress

Comment: The examples that I have seen dont seems to have this kind of problem.  would $scope.$watch($$phase){$scope.$apply();} would help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling search function on ng-change like following

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" id="txtTitle" ng-change="search()" ng-model="txtToSearch">
```

solved the issue. but I am still trying to find out why it isn't working on search button. change search controller as well and here is code

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http, $location, CS) {
$scope.search = function() {  
    $scope.result = null;
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/search?title=' + $scope.txtToSearch }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.results = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });     
};

$scope.edit=function(c)
{
    CourseService.set(course);
    $location.path('/edit');
}



}
```